# Can I use phyl.vcv function in "phytools" to compute a phylogenetic Pearson r

Tags: r, phylogeny, pearson-correlation

The phyl.vcv function in 'phytools' R package computes a phylogenetic trait variance-covariance matrix between two variables.

Can I use this matrix to compute a phylogenetic Pearson r value? If so, can this r-value be used in a t test (with n-2 df) to test the significance of the correlation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liam Revell posted a solution on his blog here with R code: http://blog.phytools.org/2017/08/pearson-correlation-with-phylogenetic.html